# Accessing resources from a Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm developing a Qt application that is using many resources (music, sounds, images) from external files.

I don't want to use the Qt Resources System, as the size of my resources is big.

Here is my dev folder-structure :

```
myApp+-res+-images- *.jpg, *.png images
     |    |
     |    +-sounds- *.wav sounds
     |
     +-src- myApp.pro
            *.cpp files
            *.h files
```

When I compile and run my program from Qt Creator, in debug mode, the application path is this one :

```
.../myApp/build-GameFramework-Desktop_Qt_6_3_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/debug
```

so, my resources files are in this relative location : `../../res/`

This relative location is the same if I compile and run my program from Qt Creator in release mode.

But when I want to deploy my program, my `res` folder is in the same folder as my application :

```
myApp+-res+-images- *.jpg, *.png images
     |    |
     |    +-sounds- *.wav sounds
     |
     +-myApp.exe
```

This means my resources files are now in this relative location : `res/`, which is not the same as when I'm developing my app.

Is there a way to have my resources at the same relative location, no matter if I run my app from Qt Creator or from my application folder ?

If not, what is the best/easiest way to cope with this problem ?

Comment: I think this is normally done by adding a step to your build process that copies the resources to the appropriate path in your build output folder. If you don't want to copy them (because they are large) maybe use symbolic links?

Comment: You can check in runtime if appdir contains `res` directory and use it, otherwise fallback to `../../res` directory

Comment: @mugiseybrows thanks ! I feel so stupid I didn't think about your solution !